# Как работать с коллекцией связанных сущностей (их изменение не требуется)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть две сущности (политики паролей и группы):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_password_policy", schema = "oauth")
public class SysPasswordPolicyEntity implements Serializable {
    private Long policyId;
    private String policyName;
    private Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupsByPolicyId;
// ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<SysGroupEntity> getSysGroupsByPolicyId() {
        return sysGroupsByPolicyId;
    }

    public void setSysGroupsByPolicyId(Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupsByPolicyId) {
        this.sysGroupsByPolicyId = sysGroupsByPolicyId;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_group", schema = "oauth")
public class SysGroupEntity implements Serializable {
    private Long groupId;
    private String groupName;
    private SysPasswordPolicyEntity sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId;

//...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "password_policy_id", referencedColumnName = "policy_id")
    public SysPasswordPolicyEntity getSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId() {
        return sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId;
    }

    public void setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(SysPasswordPolicyEntity sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId) {
        this.sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId = sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId;
    }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы:

- При создании политики можно было ей назначить какие-то группы (группы при этом не должны создаваться, и у них не должны обновляться никакие поля, кроме `sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId`)
- При обновлении политики можно было удалить из списка группу, а также добавить её в список (при этом не нужно, чтобы группы удалялись из базы, создавались в базе, и не нужно, чтобы у них в базе обновлялись все поля, кроме `sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId`; нужно, чтобы при удалении из списка значение поля `sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId` становилось `null`, при добавлении - этому полю присваивалась ссылка на текущую группу)

Как обычно решаются такие задачи? (вроде ситуация стандартная, и часто встречается)

P.S. Пытался искать в интернете, но по моей ситуации сложно что-то найти, а по связанным общим темам пока ничего не нашёл.

PSS Пока реализовано так:

```
    @Override
    public SysPasswordPolicyEntity persist(SysPasswordPolicyEntity entity) {
        setRelationObjects(entity, false);
        return super.persist(entity);
    }

@Override
    public SysPasswordPolicyEntity update(SysPasswordPolicyEntity entity) {
        setRelationObjects(entity, false);
        return super.persist(entity);
    }

       private void setRelationObjects(SysPasswordPolicyEntity entity, boolean isUpdate) {

        if (entity == null)
            return;

            final Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupsFromRest = entity.getSysGroupsByPolicyId();

            if (!isUpdate) {
                sysGroupsFromRest.stream() // добавление нового
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .forEach(
                                sysGroupEntity -> {
                                    sysGroupEntity.setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(entity);

                                    final Long groupId = sysGroupEntity.getGroupId();
                                    if (groupId != null) {
                                        Optional.ofNullable(sysGroupDao.findById(groupId))
                                                .ifPresent(sysGroupEntityfromDB -> {
                                                    sysGroupEntityfromDB.setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(entity); 
                                                    sysGroupDao.update(sysGroupEntityfromDB);
                                                });
                                    }
                                }
                        );

            } else {
                final Session session = getSession();
                final Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupEntitiesFromDB = Optional.ofNullable(findById(entity.getPolicyId()))
                        .map(entityFromDB -> {
                            session.evict(entityFromDB);
                            return entityFromDB;
                        })
                        .map(SysPasswordPolicyEntity::getSysGroupsByPolicyId)
                        .orElse(Set.of());

                sysGroupEntitiesFromDB.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(Predicate.not(sysGroupsFromRest::contains))
                        .forEach(
                        sysGroupEntityFromDB -> 
                                Optional.ofNullable(sysGroupDao.findById(sysGroupEntityFromDB.getGroupId()))
                                        .ifPresent(sysGroupEntityfromDB -> {
                                            session.evict(sysGroupEntityfromDB.getSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId());
                                            sysGroupEntityfromDB.setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(null);
                                            sysGroupDao.update(sysGroupEntityfromDB);
                                        })
                );

                sysGroupsFromRest.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(Predicate.not(sysGroupEntitiesFromDB::contains))
                        .forEach(sysGroupEntityFromREST -> {
                            Optional.ofNullable(sysGroupEntityFromREST.getGroupId())
                                    .map(sysGroupDao::findById)
                                    .ifPresent(sysGroupEntityfromDB -> {
                                        sysGroupEntityfromDB.setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(entity);
                                        sysGroupDao.update(sysGroupEntityfromDB);
                                    });
                });
            }
    }
```

Comment: сделал пока с ручным апдейтом при сейве или апдейте родительской сущности. Работает, но выглядит коряво, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по описанной структуре основная сущность - группа. Данные храняться в поле sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId для писанной связи - поэтому вы назначаете политику группе а не наоборот.

Соответственно когда вы меняете политику, то это не должно менять ссылки на нее.

Если надо поменять ссылку на политику, то это по сути отдельная операция где обновляется не политика а группа.

Если по бизнес требованиям надо проделать какую-либо работу с ссылками из-за изменения политики, то эту логику можно вынести в слушатель. Т.е. сохранение политики в конце публикует событие о том что политика изменена, соответствующий слушатель перехватывает это изменение и вызывает необходимый метод в сервисе работы с группами.Таким образом вы не привязываете сервис политики к сервису групп и будут поделены зоны ответственности.

Comment: то есть всё равно принудительно вызывать апдейт у сессии?

Comment: если вы хотите изменить сущность группы, вы делаете ее save - что именно вас в этом смущает?

Comment: Обычно хибернейт сам всё делает: сохраняет коллекции вместе с сущностью, например

Comment: У вас поле коллекции помечено как lazy поле (и исходя из логики это правильно), hibernate не инициализирует данное поле без вызова метода get, соответственно на момент сохранения правила, данное поле может быть равно null. И потом на момент сохранения группы вы удаляете связь с правилом - обнуляете поле sysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId, соответственно данная группа с правилом уже никак не связана, если я вас правильно понял.

Comment: Почему на момент сохранения я удаляю связь с группой? при апдейте или сейве я могу как удалить связь, так и добавить новую. Или вообще ничего не сделать с этой связью

Comment: выложите, пожалуйста метод сохранения политики и метод сохранения группы.

Comment: Выложил, как сейчас выглядят методы сохранения и обновления политики. В методах для групп нет упоминаний политик, поэтому их не привожу

Comment: Очень странная логика. В строке `final Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupsFromRest = entity.getSysGroupsByPolicyId();` hibernate  вернет вам все сущности групп у которых проставлена ссылка на политику. Дальше вы в цикле берете сущность группы и вызываете метод `sysGroupEntity.setSysPasswordPolicyByPasswordPolicyId(entity)`,этот id итак уже задан у всех сущностей групп которые вы подняли, иначе hibernate вам их не найдет, он их ищет по этому идентификатору. Когда делаете обновление, то не понятно зачем вы все эти сущности предварительно чистите.

Comment: Написано неоправданно сложно - не дай Бог такое поддерживать в будущем. И опять же - этой логике не место в сохранении правила. Используйте паттерн наблюдатель (слушатель). Почитать описание его реализации можно здесь https://systems-ez.ru/index.php/ru/patterns/33-observer. И в Spring и в JEE есть уже реализованные механизмы их просто надо использовать.

Comment: "В строке `final Set<SysGroupEntity> sysGroupsFromRest = entity.getSysGroupsByPolicyId();` hibernate вернет вам все сущности групп у которых проставлена ссылка на политику. " - неправильно пишите. Это берётся коллекция у пришедшего объекта. А он можно прийти извне через REST API данного приложения.

Comment: И мы сейчас не говорим о том, где располагать этот код. Тут надо сначала понять, нужен ли он. Есть ли другой способ это сделать. По идеи двустороннее связывание объектов (на уровне ссылок, до вызова метода `save()` или `update()`) должно быть достаточно для того, чтобы произошло сохранение или удаление, как в этой статье: https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/

Comment: Если мы говорим о REST то вам от туда entity прилететь не может, вам прилетает JSON который как правило парсится на DTO дальше есть какой-то маппер который знает как из этого DTO сделать Entity объект. Прежде чем вносить изменения в Entity надо чтоб Hibernate его нашел или создал. В противном случае он об этой сущности вообще ничего не знает.

Comment: У нас это сразу парсится в `entity` (в смысле, что промежуточных DTO-классов нет, используется класс Entity). Ну и для того, чтобы `hibernate` узнал об этой сущности, я вызываю `findById()` перед `update()`

Comment: Кажется я теперь только понял вашу задачу - у вас правила меняются где-то на стороне, и все что вам надо это синхронизировать ваш объект с тем который к вам прилетел. Я вас правильно понимаю?

Comment: Ну, конечно, список групп, связанных с политикой меняется не на бэкенде, а на фронтенде (в интерфейсе пользователя). Связь фронтенда с бэкендом осуществляется через REST API.
Правда, я так же могу редактировать этот список и на бэкенде.